# Finding all the possible values of an Integral in the Complex Plane

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am studying Complex Analysis by Lars V Ahlfors. I am unable to solve one of his exercises. It is:

Find all possible values of $$\int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$
over a closed curve.

I do not have any clue as to how to solve the above problem, if the denominator terms like $z-z_0$ then I can try winding a curve around $z_0$. But in this in particular question I cannot think of any way to approach it. If anyone can give some hints it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Exercise 5 in chapter 4, section 4? There is a restriction on the closed curves there.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Is it not like there are two parts to the question and this is the second part? But still I am interested in knowing if there is some definite answer for all curves

Comment: The first part is the existence of branches of the function on certain open sets. In the second part, we deal with closed curves in such a region. That means we need not consider the possibility that a curve intersects a branch-cut or the like, which would make the problem somewhat more complicated.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer but if we calculate integral on closed curve where it is analytic will the answer not just be zero?

Comment: You know that only when the integrand is analytic also in the complete region enclosed by $\gamma$. That need not be the case.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer a small question regarding your above comment: If the function is analytic then we can find a small neighbourhood such that it is a power series then in that small region we can find the primitive. Now let us cover the curve with small balls such that the function permits a series expansion. Now by applying the Mean value theorem for each ball and then adding all the sums wont we get that sum is zero for any curve?

Comment: No, that only works if the local primitives fit together. You know that it doesn't work for $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{dz}{z},$$ and when the integral is non-zero, it's the same principle at work, the local primitives don't fit together along the whole curve. In more grandiose terms (coming later in the book), the analytic continuation of a local primitive along the curve doesn't lead back to the original.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thanks a lot learnt something new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise considers regions in the complex plane such that the two points $1$ and $-1$ belong to the same component of the complement. On such regions, an analytic branch of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ exists, which is the first part of the exercise, and the second part asks for the possible values of

$$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$

where $\gamma$ is a closed curve (suitable for integration) in such a region.

The two most used regions to define branches of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ are:

- $U = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ t\in\mathbb{R} : \lvert t\rvert \geqslant 1\}$, where $1$ and $-1$ belong to the same component of the complement of $U$ in the sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, but not to the same component of the complement in the plane, so it is arguable whether this region or similar ones are to be considered. $U$ is simply connected, so Cauchys integral theorem immediately yields the vanishing of all the integrals in that case.
- $V = \mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$, and in this case it is easy to see that the value of the integral only depends on how often $\gamma$ winds around the interval $[-1,1]$, so the value of the integral is $n(\gamma,1)\cdot C$ for some constant $C$, which I leave for you to find.

Now what remains is to see that every case can be reduced to one of the above. Since there are no assumptions on the niceness of the complement, the argument, when made precise, is a little tedious (Hint: the trace of the curve $\gamma$ is a compact set, hence has a positive distance from the complement, which allows you to replace the complement with a nicer set).